# SASS compile fontawesome preserve notation

Tags: sass, font-awesome

When I compile fontawesome.scss to a css file with sass 3.4.1

```
$fa-var-music: "\f001"; 
.#{$fa-css-prefix}-music:before { content: $fa-var-music; }
```

it is compiled to

```
.fa-music:before {
  content: "";
}
```

As I'm mainly using Win1252 encoding in my project I'm wondering what's the way to preserve "\f001" in the css file. Why does SASS rewrite?

Comment: \f001 literally produces the character at code point F001 (hex), which is not valid in Windows-1252. What character are you trying to produce?

Comment: Don't have the why, but it is worth noting that Sass also injects the charset information when it does this: `@charset "UTF-8";` (see: http://sassmeister.com/gist/4c326a38bf0457f120db).

Comment: @ljacqu I don't try to produce characters myself. I want to use the chars provided by font awesome. My fear is - when the file contains unicode characters - the fa symbols might not be rendered correctly by some browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extract from Sass 3.4.0 [changelog](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_CHANGELOG.html):
Sass now follows the CSS Syntax Level 3 specification for determining a stylesheet’s encoding. In addition, it now only emits UTF-8 CSS rather than trying to match the source encoding.

Now no way for use old method

[Issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1395) on SASS repo

For me, rollback to SASS 3.3.14 fix this

Comment: As SASS correctly outputs `@charset "UTF-8";`in the very first line there's no real trouble as long as the generated file is not combined with other css files and is not the first.

Comment: I simply did `$fatag: "\f02b";` (adding quotes) and that fixed it for me. No need to revert back to 3.3.14.

Comment: I'm using 4.2.0. I've added the @charset "UTF-8" to the top of the _variables file, however all of the UTF/PUA character codes are already in double quotes yet I'm still getting the same funky shape.

Does anyone have any further information?

Comment: btw. I had an old version of yui compressor running. It had changed in the meantime. `@charset "UTF-8"` is now pulled to the very top of the combined and compressed css file and therefore being parsed and used correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gulp to compile your CSS, you can install this gulp plugin and it will automatically fix the issue for you. No Sass code alterations necessary.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-unicode

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sassUnicode = require('gulp-sass-unicode');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
  gulp.src('style.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(sassUnicode()) // << This line is what does the magic
    .pipe(gulp.dest( "css/" ));
});
```