# font-awesome rendered as question mark

Tags: css, asp.net, sass, font-awesome

iam using font-awesome (sass version - [Link](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass)) in my asp.net site.

i have the problem that all fonts is rendered as `?`

i have chek many times font path and css class but all seem correct

this is my html: `<i class="fa fa-magic"></i>`

inspecting the page with firebug i see `fontawesome-webfont.woff` correctly loaded

folder structure is complex since i use `bundleTransformer` to render all sass files

i have

```
Style
- fonts
  - font-awesome
- Sass
  - External
    - font-awesome
      - font-awesome
```

bottom level `font-awesome` folder contains all font-awesome .scss files

this is the path in `_variables.scss`:

```
$fa-font-path: if($fa-sass-asset-helper, "font-awesome/", "fonts/font-awesome/") !default;
```

upper `font-awesome` folder contains `_font-awesome.scss` that import all .scss

external folder contains `__external.scss`
with this code: `@import "font-awesome/font-awesome";`

in `sass` folder i have my `application.scss` file:

```
@import "Base/placeholders";
@import "Base/mixins";
@import "Pages/__pages";
@import "Modules/__modules";
@import "External/__external";
```

finally style is rendered with this boundle:

```
var commonStylesBundle = new CustomStyleBundle("~/Style/tema");
        commonStylesBundle.Include("~/Style/Sass/application.scss");
        commonStylesBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
        commonStylesBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
        bundles.Add(commonStylesBundle);
```

and added in this way to `masterpage` `head:

```
<%# Styles.Render("~/Style/tema") %>
```

The page looks for file in this path:

```
/Style/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

and finds it

i have try BootstrapCDN by MaxCDN and it works fine but i can't use it since our user can browse only in local network and can't use internet resources

Comment: is your server setup have the correct mime type?

Comment: i have the issue even locally with visual studio, i also add  `<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/x-woff" />` to `web.config` but with no success

Comment: Why not use absolute path to font-awesome website to de-bug

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488037/sass-compile-fontawesome-preserve-notation

Comment: firefox 40 and ie8, with absolute path to font-awesome website (<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
) all works fine

Comment: @cimmanon i have "?" not square symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking deeper in solution i found that an edit made for `AjaxControlToolkit` `MaskedEdit` by other developer altered the standard encoding.

setting it back to UTF-8 solved this problem.

thanks to @cimmanon for link where i read about char encoding