# SASS content with variable unicode

Tags: sass

I'm trying to be able to feed variable unicode to a SASS mixin, this way I don't have .after/.before in every single icon class.

What I have so far:

```
@mixin placement($icon) {
  &.after:after   { content: '#{$icon}'; }
  &.before:before { content: '#{$icon}'; }
}
.icon_dashboard {
  @include placement('\f0e4');
}
```

However upon compiling the \ screws things up, is there anyway around this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488037/sass-compile-fontawesome-preserve-notation